# Media Player has weird behavior

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-mediaplayer

I have a section in my app that load media players with url in a recycler view.
Sometimes the Play with url mp3 is not a valid file but i need to show it without anything neither playing the mp3 file ofcourse because it's already not valid.
My problem is media player not working properly when using `prepareAsync` even if it is a valid file mp3 it's not working, i knew it because of reloading the same files sometimes working and sometimes not working. whenever if the all files are valid the `prepare` method works perfect and prepareAsync not working properly. here is my recyclerview bindview holder code

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AudioRecycleViewAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

        try {
            // Get the data model based on position
            final PlayAudioModel model = mVisitHistory.get(position);

            // Set item views based on your views and data model
            final ImageView playControllerImageView = viewHolder.playControllerImageView;
            final ProgressBar playProgressBar = viewHolder.playProgressBar;
            CircleImageView userImageView = viewHolder.userImageView;
            TextView timeTextView = viewHolder.timeTextView;
            final TextView durationTextView = viewHolder.durationTextView;

            if (model.getSenderType().equals("doctor")) {
                Glide.with(mContext).load(Constants.SERVER_IP + Constants.GET_DOCTOR_IMAGE_FOR_VISIT_HISTORY
                        .replace("{visitRequestId}", "" + model.getVisitRequestId())
                        .replace("{doctorId}", "" + model.getDoctorId())
                      ).into(userImageView);
                userImageView.setBorderColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));

            } else {
                Glide.with(mContext).load(Constants.SERVER_IP + Constants.GET_PATIENT_IMAGE
                       ).into(userImageView);
                userImageView.setBorderColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            }
            timeTextView.setText(DateHelper.convertStringUtcToLocalDate(model.getTime()));


            mp.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                    System.out.println();
                    return false;
                }
            });

            mp.setDataSource(Constants.SERVER_IP + Constants.PLAY_AUDIO
                   
                    .replace("{recordId}", "" + model.getVoiceRecordId()));

            mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer mp) {


                    playProgressBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());

                    double mins = Math.floor((mp.getDuration() % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                    double secs = Math.floor((mp.getDuration() % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
                    durationTextView.setText((int) mins + ":" + (int) secs);


                    final CountDownTimer mpTimer = new CountDownTimer(mp.getDuration(), 1) {
                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                            playProgressBar.setProgress(mp.getDuration() - (int) millisUntilFinished);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish() {
                            playControllerImageView.setImageDrawable(mContext.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_play_circle));
                            playProgressBar.setProgress(0);

                        }
                    };
                    playControllerImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {


                            if (!mp.isPlaying()) {

                                mpTimer.start();
                                mp.start();
                                playControllerImageView.setImageDrawable(mContext.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_pause));
                            } else {
                                mp.pause();
                                mpTimer.cancel();
                                playProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                                playControllerImageView.setImageDrawable(mContext.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_play_circle));

                            }

                        }
                    });

                }
            });
            mp.prepareAsync();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I Solved the problem by creating a media player in the model which i use in `RecyclerView` and i did all operation like error listener and prepareAsync in the model since the recycler view recreate the whole object, and this was my problem, `prepareAsync` is now working like charm!, note that i left the `onPrepared` callback in recycler view and i did something like this

```
musics.get(position).getMediaPlayer().setOnPreparedListener(...)
```